# How to retain the values of radio buttons from listview in android on orientation change

Tags: android, listview, android-radiobutton

I have different layouts for landscape and portrait mode. When I select the values from radio buttons in radio group and change the orientation , new layout is displayed and all values are vanished. Please Help.

```
package com.hp.opiniondesknew;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.os.ParcelableCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Created by HP on 15-12-2016.
 */

public class FragmentFeedback extends Fragment {



    private ArrayList<Questions> questionsArrayList;
    HashMap<Questions, String> mapAns=new HashMap<Questions, String>();
    private MyAdapter myAdapter;
    private ListView listFeedbackQuestions;
    private Button btSubmitFeedback;
    private String selectedAns;
    ArrayList<String> rbAnswersArray = new ArrayList<>();

    int yesCount=0,noCount=0;
    Questions questionPojo;

    public FragmentFeedback() {

//        setRetainInstance(true);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.feedback_layout,container,false);

        listFeedbackQuestions= (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.opinion_desk_feedback_lv_questions);
        btSubmitFeedback=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.opinion_desk_feedback_bt_submit);

                questionsArrayList= new ArrayList<Questions>();


        addlistview();
        initializeBtnSubmit(btSubmitFeedback);
        return view;
    }

    private void initializeBtnSubmit( Button btSubmitFeedback) {



            btSubmitFeedback.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    //---------

                    try
                    {

                        for(Map.Entry m:mapAns.entrySet()){
//                            System.out.println(m.getKey"()+" "+m.getValue());
                            Log.e("key value",m.getKey()+""+m.getValue());
                        }
                        if(mapAns.size()==0 || mapAns.size()< questionsArrayList.size())
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Ans all q",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            int countYes = Collections.frequency(mapAns.values(), "yes");
                            {
                                Log.e("yescount",countYes+"");
                            }

                            int countNo = Collections.frequency(mapAns.values(), "no");
                            {
                                Log.e("noCount",countNo+"");
                                Log.e("mapsize",mapAns.size()+"");
                            }

                            if(countYes>countNo)
                            {

                                Fragment someFragment = new FragmentTestimonial();
                                FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                                transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, someFragment ); // give your fragment container id in first parameter
//                                transaction.addToBackStack(null);  // if written, this transaction will be added to backstack
                                transaction.commit();
                                Log.e("noCount",countNo+"");
                                Log.e("yescount",countYes+"");
//                                Log.e("yes is greater",rbAnswersArray.size()+"");

                            }
                            else
                            {

                                Fragment someFragment = new FragmentSuggestions();
                                FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                                transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, someFragment ); // give your fragment container id in first parameter
//                                transaction.addToBackStack(null);  // if written, this transaction will be added to backstack
                                transaction.commit();
                                Log.e("noCount",countNo+"");
                                Log.e("yescount",countYes+"");

                            }
                            mapAns.clear();
                        }


                    }catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}

                    //-----

                }
            });

    }




    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        getActivity().setTitle("Feedback");
    }

    public void addlistview()
    {
        try
        {
            for (int i=0;i<5;i++) {
                Questions questions = new Questions();

//                questions.setQuestion(i+"");
                questions.setQuestion("Did you like the performance of the service?");
                questions.setQuestionNo(i);
                questionsArrayList.add(questions);

                myAdapter = new MyAdapter(getContext(), questionsArrayList);
                listFeedbackQuestions.setAdapter(myAdapter);

                if(selectedState != null) {
                    listFeedbackQuestions.onRestoreInstanceState(selectedState);
                }

//                Log.e("pojo",questions.toString());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}



    }

    public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        Context context;
        ArrayList<Questions> questionsArrayList;
        LayoutInflater inflator;

        public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Questions> questionsArrayList) {
            this.context = context;
            this.questionsArrayList = questionsArrayList;
            inflator= LayoutInflater.from(context);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {

            return questionsArrayList.size();
        }


        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return questionsArrayList.get(position);
        }


        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }


        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
//            Questions questionsPojo= new Questions();
       Holder holder= new Holder();
            if(convertView==null)
            {
                convertView=inflator.inflate(R.layout.feedback_question_row,parent,false);
                holder.tvQuestion=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.opinion_desk_feedback_tv_question);
                holder.rGroupButtons=(RadioGroup)convertView.findViewById(R.id.opinion_desk_rg_yes_no);
                holder.rbYes=(RadioButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.opinion_desk_feedback_rb_yes);
                holder.rbNo=(RadioButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.opinion_desk_feedback_rb_no);

                convertView.setTag(holder);

            }
            else
            {
                holder=(Holder)convertView.getTag();
            }

            questionPojo=questionsArrayList.get(position);

            holder.tvQuestion.setText(questionsArrayList.get(position).getQuestion());
            final Holder finalHolder = holder;
            holder.rGroupButtons.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

                if (finalHolder.rbYes.isChecked())
                {
                    Log.e("no",position+"");

                    finalHolder.selectedAnswer="yes";
                    questionsArrayList.get(position).setAnswer(finalHolder.selectedAnswer);

                    selectedAns=  questionsArrayList.get(position).getAnswer();

                    rbAnswersArray.add(selectedAns);

                    yesCount++;

                }
                else

                {
                    Log.e("no",position+"");

                    finalHolder.selectedAnswer="no";
                    questionsArrayList.get(position).setAnswer(finalHolder.selectedAnswer);
                    selectedAns=questionsArrayList.get(position).getAnswer();


                    noCount++;

           }
                    mapAns.put(questionsArrayList.get(position),selectedAns);
                    rbAnswersArray.add(selectedAns);
//
                }
            });



            return convertView;
        }
    }


    public class Holder
    {
        TextView tvQuestion;
        RadioGroup rGroupButtons;
        RadioButton rbYes,rbNo, rbSelectedAnswer;
        String selectedAnswer, ansNo;

    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroyOptionsMenu() {
        super.onDestroyOptionsMenu();


    }

//    @Override
//    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
//        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
//    }
}
```

I am using listview and custom adapter for the listview. I am launching the fragment feedback from navigation activity. OnSavedInstanceState is not working, applictaion is crashing in onRestore method.I might be doing something wrong.

Comment: save your selected positions on Orientation change(onSaveInstanceState) and use it after that.

Comment: I am new to android development. Could you suggest some way regarding how can i save the position?

Comment: This is a complete solution http://www.gitshah.com/2011/03/how-to-handle-screen-orientation_28.html.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `Bundle savedInstanceState` to retrive your values.
You can save them in the `onSaveInstanceState` method.

Here a link to the documentation https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html